# RxJava - retry: reset retry counter on successful resume

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2

Currently I'm using Observable.retry(n) in order to retry in case of error. Please take a look at this code:

```
@Test
public void testObservableRetry() {
    Observable
            .<String>defer(() -> Observable
                    .just(Notification.createOnNext("valid value"), Notification.createOnError(new Error("Test")))
                    .dematerialize())
            .doOnNext(v -> System.out.println("onNext: " + v))
            .doOnError(e -> System.out.println("onError: " + e.getMessage()))
            .doOnSubscribe(d -> System.out.println("onSubscribe"))
            .doOnDispose(() -> System.out.println("onDispose"))
            .retry(2)
            .take(2) // .take(4) will fail the test
            .blockingLast();
}
```

The code above is able to resume after error, but the retry number is limited for total errors number and not consecutive errors.

E.g. if you replace `.take(2)` with `.take(4)` - the test will fail, because total errors number will exceed 4, despite the fact that after each error it resumes and is able to get next value:

```
---(v1)----(error)---(v2)----(error)----(v3)-----(error)---(v4)-
```

I'd like to find a way to reset a counter after successful resume. The use case is for example network connection - I'd like to give the same number of tries on each disconnection, but after each successful connect I'd like to reset the counter in order to allow endless flow unless each time it's able to resume within constant number of tries.

**EDIT:**

Successful resume in this context means receiving at least 1 item after retry. So I'd like to limit only the number of consecutive errors, and not total errors.

Comment: I don't understand the requirements. Do you want to retry at most 2 times if a run results in an immediate error and retry indefinitely if there was at least one item?

Comment: @akarnokd. Yes, if after retry there was at least one item - I'd like to reset the retry counter and on next error to try at most 2 times again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `retryWhen` and communicate with it from before the flow:

```java
@Test
public void emptyError() {
    AtomicInteger c = new AtomicInteger();
    Observable.fromCallable(() -> { throw new Exception("" + c.incrementAndGet()); })
    .compose(retryEmpty(2))
    .test()
    .assertFailureAndMessage(Exception.class, "2");
}

@Test
public void nonEmptyError() {
    Observable.just(1).concatWith(Observable.error(new Exception()))
    .compose(retryEmpty(2))
    .take(4)
    .test()
    .assertResult(1, 1, 1, 1);
}

static <T> ObservableTransformer<T, T> retryEmpty(int count) {
    return o ->
        Observable.defer(() -> {
            AtomicInteger remaining = new AtomicInteger(count);
            AtomicBoolean nonEmpty = new AtomicBoolean();

            return o.doOnNext(v -> nonEmpty.lazySet(true))
            .retryWhen(err -> 
                err.flatMap(e -> {
                    if (nonEmpty.get()) {
                        nonEmpty.lazySet(false);
                        remaining.lazySet(count);
                    } else
                    if (remaining.decrementAndGet() == 0) {
                        return Observable.error(e);
                    }
                    return Observable.just(1);
                })
             );
        });
}
```

Comment: Nice solution! Works like a charm. I didn't thought in direction of Observable.compose / ObservableTransformer. I tried to find a way with retryWhen - but was stuck on the need to be notified onNext of the upstream observable. Compose definitely did the trick. Just one suggestion - nonEmpty flag seems a bit redundant. You can just use o.doOnNext(v -> remaining.lazySet(count)) in order to reset the counter

Answer (score 3):

This is just a little bit modified @akarnokd's solution (just removing `nonEmpty` flag). @akarnokd - Fill free to edit your solution and I will delete this one.

```
static <T> ObservableTransformer<T, T> retryEmpty(int count) {
    return o -> {
        AtomicInteger remaining = new AtomicInteger(count);
        return o.doOnNext(v -> remaining.lazySet(count))
                .retryWhen(err -> err.flatMap(e ->
                                (remaining.decrementAndGet() == 0)
                                        ? Observable.<T>error(e)
                                        : Observable.just(1)));
    };
}
```

Comment: I would like to add, that implementation might cause loops, when a #startWith-operator is used. When a failure happens, the source is re-subscribed and the #startWith-operator emits an event. By emitting a value the counter is reset. When a failure happens right after the emit, it will re-subscribe and start at zero. This is something, which you have to take into account.